# Data binding not updating view text

Tags: android, data-binding, observable, viewmodel

I am using below code implementing data binding with `Observable`

Observable

```
class Model() : BaseObservable() {

    private var  date :Long?=null
    private var  from :String?=null
    private var  to :String?=null


    @Bindable
    fun getFrom(): String? {
        return from
    }

    @Bindable
    fun getDate(): Long? {
        return date
    }

    @Bindable
    fun getTo(): String? {
        return to
    }

    fun setFrom(data: String) {
        from=data
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.from);
    }

    fun setTo(data: String) {
        to=data
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.to)
    }


    fun setDate(data: Long) {
        date=data
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.date)

    }

    fun formatDate():String? {
        return date?.let { it1 -> TBDate(it1).format("dd MMM, yyyy") }

    }

}
```

xml’s view

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tip_date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_16"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_18"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/today"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/today"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/today">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/date"
        android:text="@{model.formatDate()}"
        android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onClickDate()}"
        android:editable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        tools:text="12 Feb, Wednesday" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Java

```
override fun onClickXYZ () {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    viewModel.setDate(calendar.timeInMillis)
}
```

**Expected Behaviour**-Whenever date value of `Observable` is changed using `setDate()`, view should update date value in proper format

**Actual behaviour**-View doesn’t update date value.Observable’s `setDate()` getting called but `formatDate()` not getting called

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
 var formattedDate: String? = null


 fun setDate(data: Long) {
     date=data
     formatDate(date)
     notifyPropertyChanged(BR.date)
 }

 fun formatDate(date: Long):String? {
     formattedDate = date.let { it1 -> TBDate(it1).format("dd MMM, yyyy") }
     notifyPropertyChanged(BR.formattedDate)
 }
```

And in the xml you must use:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/date"
        android:text="@{model.formattedDate}"  <--
        ...
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: formatDate() returns a string( which is date in proper format).And your code not using that returned formatted string anywhere.

Comment: notifyPropertyChanged for formatted date not called.After adding that I found that if setFrom() and setTo() are called before setDate() then date view doesn't update

Comment: If you're going for the above approach, you also need to make the field formattedDate bindable and call notifyPropertyChanged(BR.formattedDate) and an appropriate getter method (e.g. getFormattedDate).  This will notify any observers on that field (e.g. the textfield) and update the view